# How to hide a part of a geometry dynamically using a shader in three.js

Tags: glsl, three.js

I have a very big geometry in three.js and I want to hide a section of that geometry along an axis (for example every vertex with a Z>N must be hidden). My idea is to create a custom shader in GLSL that does something like:

```
if vertex.z>n {
vertex.hide= True
}
```

I have 2 questions:

1. I have to do that in real time several times with different N
   values provided by the user, can I use something that "tells" to the shader the N value dynamically without creating and assign every time a new shader with just a different value?
2. Maybe that's a better way? You must consider that to compute a new
   geometry and rendering it takes like 10 seconds, so I would
   definitely avoid creating a new "cut" geometry every time.

Sorry for my poor English and thanks.

Comment: Why don't you use something like a frustrum? https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/math/Frustum

Comment: @Reynolds That's could be interesting, do you have any idea about how to manipulate the camera frustum in that way?